# Node js find data from mongo db and projec them with ejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

I am having a problem in my eshop project get request where i try to access the name and description of my products in mongodb and i can't. If i console log the products it's ok but i can't access each field separately and pass it with ejs in the client.

```
app.get("/products", function(req, res) {

  Product.find({}, function(err, products) {

    if (err) {

      console.log(err);

    } 
else {
      console.log(products);

      res.render("products", {

        productTitle: products.name,
        productDescription: products.description

      });
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Hi there! You are unable to access the `name` and `description` property because the `Product.find()` database query would return all the products you have in the DB i.e the result of the query is an array of products not a single product object. Question; Do you intend to display all or just a single product with the `GET /products` route?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it because what if you have more than one product.
So you have to loop through your products array in your ejs.

You have to render as below.

res.render("products", {

```
products: products;
```

});
}

And then you can loop through your products array in your ejs view.

Comment: I appreciat it Dharmik!Thanks!